# DRF JSONRenderer 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to follow a tutorial for `Django Rest Framework` and `VueJS` to make them work together. While using `JSONRenderer` `render` function is now giving me an issue of:

```
AttributeError: 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'get'
```

My list view is :

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from rest_framework.permissions import AllowAny
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .models import Cat
from .renderers import CatJSONRenderer
from .serializers import CatSerializer, CatListSerializer
class CatListApiView(ListAPIView):
    model = Cat
    queryset = Cat.objects.all()
    permissions_classes = (AllowAny, )
    renderer_classes = (CatJSONRenderer, )
    serializer_class = CatListSerializer
```

My renderers.py is:

```
class CatJSONRenderer(JSONRenderer):
    charset = 'utf-8'
    def render(self, data, media_type=None, renderer_context=None):
        print(data)
        errors = data.get('errors', None)

        if errors is not None:
            return super(CatJSONRenderer, self).render(data)

        return json.dumps({'cats': data})
```

And Traceback is:

```
Traceback:

File "/home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/londonyogavidya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "/home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/londonyogavidya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  156.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/londonyogavidya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  154.                 response = response.render()

File "/home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/londonyogavidya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/home/ytsejam/.virtualenvs/londonyogavidya/lib/python3.7/site-packages/rest_framework/response.py" in rendered_content
  72.         ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)

File "/home/ytsejam/public_html/londoner/yogavidya/apps/cat/renderers.py" in render
  7.         errors = data.get('errors', None)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /api/cats/
Exception Value: 'ReturnList' object has no attribute 'get'
```

How can I solve this problem ? Thanks

Comment: Please show the view. As the error says, it looks like `data` is an instance of ReturnList, and not a dict.

Comment: `json.dumps()` will give you a string.  The string won't have a 'get' attribute.  Have you tried `return {'cats': data}`?

Comment: I tried that still same mistake.

Comment: @Rachel the error is happening before that line.

Comment: Error is happening in errors line.

Comment: added ListView in case of anything.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I missed that.  Thanks for the catch.  Does your serializer class return a list?

Comment: If I remove the data.errors it returns a Json answer.

Comment: Does your serializer class return a list or a dictionary?  The renderer is trying to access a dictionary.  If it's getting a list from the serializer, the list will not have a `get` attribute.

Comment: this is what I get "{"cats": [{"id": 1, "owner": "BURAK AKIN", "name": "Duam", "age": 5, "photo": "https://placekitten.com/200/300"}, {"id": 2, "owner": "BURAK AKIN", "name": "beyinemar", "age": 3, "photo": "https://placekitten.com/200/300"}]}"

Comment: the value following `"cats"`, is the `data` segment and is a list.  No `get` attribute.  My best guess is your serializer, `CatListSerializer`, is returning a list instead of a dictionary.  The renderer is trying to display the list and apply dictionary attributes to it.  Modify either the renderer to expect a list or the serializer to return a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this by installing `django-rest-framework-json-api.` If anyone faces problem , this is transforming `dict`  to `JSON`.

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the right way to solve this problem, but rather it is a suggestion more or less like a workaround. I found out that without pagination of the resource it returns the `data` with the type
`<class 'rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnList'>`. The actual expected output and yet processable by the `render()` method of the `renderer` class is `<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>`. What I did was implement pagination with the resource as pagination returns  `<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>`. The snippet below are sample of my code for seekers review.

```
class CategoryList(MyListCreateAPIView): 
    #without the pagination implementation
    queryset = Category.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CategorySerializer
    ... # for brevity
    renderer_classes = (CategoryJSONRenderer,)
```

The initial resource url is `http://localhost:8000/categories/`

```
class CategoryList(MyListCreateAPIView):
    # with pagination implementation
    ... # for brevity
    pagination_class = StandardResultsSetPagination
```

The resource url now looks something like `http://localhost:8000/categories/?limit=5`.
Paginating the resource does the whole trick.

This whole workaround was inpired by the [Github comment](https://github.com/django-json-api/django-rest-framework-json-api/issues/53#issuecomment-127777990)  made by [@jsenecal](https://github.com/jsenecal).